# sqlite3.programmingerror incorrect number of bindings supplied. the current statement uses 1 and there are 15 supplied

Tags: python

con = sqlite3.connect("dialog.db")
            print("Database connected successfully")

```
        #con.execute(
        #"create table Employees2 (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL)")

        #print("Table created successfully")


        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("insert into Employees (email) values (?);",(email))

        con.commit()
        con.close()
```

Comment: You provide a string as sequence of characters. To provide a tuple with the string as only item, write `(email,)`

Answer (score 1):

As Michael pointed out, you supplied a string, which is an `iterable` in Python. SQLite will try to loop through it. You can solve it by wrapping the string in another iterable. The easiest way to do it is to use a list or tuple

```py
cur.execute("insert into Employees (email) values (?);",(email,))
```

or

```py
cur.execute("insert into Employees (email) values (?);", [email])
```

When you use a pair of parenthesis without a comma, Python interpreted it as you are trying to change the operator precedence of the expression, instead of supplying a tuple.